# jQuery using $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabular

I have a [table](http://jsfiddle.net/zHRv4/) with some tabular data in it.

Currently I am using the below code to get information from the document **rows.html** but if I change it from `$.get` to `$.ajax` I loose the information from **rows.html** why?

```
$.get('rows.html', function(r){ //or $.post, $.ajax etc
      $('table.bordered').append(r);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.ajax` requires a `type` field to be populated with something like GET, POST, etc. Since you're fetching data, it seems like you need `type: 'GET'`. `$.post` won't help you and if you really want to use `$.ajax`, you'll need to specify the type (again, GET). http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

**EDIT**: It appears `$.ajax` will do a GET by default, but try placing everything in a hash,

```
$.ajax({url: 'rows.html', type: 'GET'}, function(r) { 
    alert(r); 
});
```